# How to update images stored as strings in extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have recently created an extension that has a file upload feature. I decided to store it as a string. I have used it like this:

In the controller:

```
    public function initializeAction() {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('blog')) {
            $this->arguments->getArgument('blog')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->setTargetTypeForSubProperty('image', 'array');
        }
    }
```

In the model:

```
  /**
   * Returns the image
   * 
   * @return string $image
   */
  public function getImage()
  {
        return $this->image;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the image
   * 
   * @param \array $image
   * @return void
   */
  public function setImage(array $image)
  {
        die(debug::var_dump($image));
        if (!empty($image['name']))
        {
              $imageName = $image['name'];
              $imageTempName = $image['tmp_name'];
              $basicFileUtility = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Utility\\File\\BasicFileUtility');
              $imageNameNew = $basicFileUtility->getUniqueName($imageName, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('uploads/tx_myextension/'));
              \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move($imageTempName, $imageNameNew);
              $this->image = basename($imageNameNew);
        }
  }
```

The TCA:

```
   'config' => [
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'file',
        'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_myextension',
        'show_thumbs' => 1,
        'size' => 1,
        'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
        'disallowed' => ''
    ],
```

In my form:

```
<f:form action="update" name="blog" object="{blog}" >
<f:form.upload property="image" class="form-control" />
...
```

Now **this works perfectly when a new object is created**, however when I try to change this image (using updateAction), I get the this error message:

```
 Exception while property mapping at property path "image":
 No converter found which can be used to convert from "string" to "array".
```

I would like to avoid uploading via FAL or writing my own conversion. I'm hoping that I just missed something trivial.

Comment: Maybe you should look here: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very stupid and simple mistake from my part. In the edit form I forgot to add this: enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<f:form action="update" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blog" object="{blog}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an look to an [update script](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/tt_address/blob/master/Classes/Updates/ImageToFileReference.php) from `tt_address` to see how to make an update.

To make it short: You must read all entries of your files and move them from upload dir to your file storage and then you must add an `file_reference` which connect the `sys_file` with your domain model:

```
GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move(
    PATH_site . 'uploads/tx_myextension/' . $imageName,
    PATH_site . 'fileadmin/tx_myextension/' . $imageName);

$fileObject = $this->storage->getFile('fileadmin/tx_myextension/' . $imageName);
if ($fileObject instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File) {
    $this->fileRepository->add($fileObject);
    $dataArray = [
        'uid_local' => $fileObject->getUid(),
        'tablenames' => 'tx_your_domain_model',
        'fieldname' => 'image',
        'uid_foreign' => 'your model uid',
        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
        'cruser_id' => 999,
        'pid' => 'your_model_pid',
        'sorting_foreign' => $imageCount,
        'sys_language_uid' => 0
    ];

    if ($this->getDatabaseConnection()->exec_INSERTquery('sys_file_reference', $dataArray)) {
        $imageCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was that I completely overlooked something very obvious.